# Xcode ld: library not found for. Can't figure out the one last missing

Tags: xcode, clang, file-not-found

**Hi 
I'm facing some of the library not found error after I move my project from one computer to another. I was able to fix most of them by retyping the library search path in build setting, but there are one last one that I can't figure out...
Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Here is the screenshot off the full error.**

"Ld /Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Products/summer.app/summer normal armv7
    cd /Users/Garett/Desktop/summer
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Products -LSocialNetworking -LSocialNetworking/FacebookSDK -LSocialNetworking/Twitter -LPrime31Shared -L/Users/Garett/Desktop -L/Volumes/xyz.archive/WHEELBARROW/W1301.01.SHAUNTAN.SummerEBook/proto/Libraries -L/Users/Garett/Desktop/summer/Prime31Shared -L/Users/Garett/Desktop/summer/SocialNetworking/FacebookSDK -L/Users/Garett/Desktop/summer/SocialNetworking/Twitter -L/Volumes/xyz.archive/WHEELBARROW/W1301.01.SHAUNTAN.SummerEBook/proto -L/Users/Garett/Desktop/summer/Libraries -L/Users/Garett/Desktop/summer/Libraries -F/Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Products -filelist /Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/summer.LinkFileList -dead_strip -all_load -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework OpenAL -liconv.2 -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -liPhone-lib -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework iAd -lP31SharedTools -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak_framework GameKit -weak_framework MessageUI -lz.1.1.3 -lP31Twitter -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -lfacebook_ios_sdk -weak_framework Twitter -framework Security -lsqlite3.0 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Intermediates/Unity-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/summer_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Garett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-hersobsdbotryocyyleucivbibaa/Build/Products/summer.app/summer"
ld: library not found for -liPhone-lib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thx